# SQL Server database connection through SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-connection, oledb, etl

I am getting this error shown in the screen shot. My database is accessible from SQL Server Mgmt Studio, but when I try to connect through the connect manager in SSIS, it isn't able to connect.

Am I missing anything here?

Provider is Native OLE DB\SQL server Native client 11.0 and I am choosing SQL Server authentication, no problem with connection credentials..

[image]

Comment: The encryption not supported error suggests you might not have the latest SQL Server 2012 Native Client patches. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server.

Comment: Let me check that and get back